# Fit items by percentage horizontally with Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to use Constraint Layout in Android Studio 3.0.1.

Gradle has the dependency:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.+'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

I am trying to design a very simple layout. I want to put an ImageView (100dp width) with a TextView next to it with the width of the entire free space.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewThumbnail"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewThumbnail"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My problem appears when I switch the layout_width of the TextView to 0dp. The layout design tab shows the widths correctly, but when the app is running on a device, the ImageView disappears.

I think I don't understand how Constraint Layout works. I've also tried to use a percentage Guideline but with the same result.

How can I set the image width to 100dp and the TextView width to the remaining free space of the parent ConstraintLayout?

Comment: Add layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" to the TextView

Comment: Just copy/pasting your layout into my IDE and changing the TextView width to 0dp works totally fine on my device. Your layout looks good to me.

Comment: @dazza5000 it doesn't work. If I set `layout_width="0dp"` with your constraint the TextView doesn't appear on the screen.
@BenP. it's so weird.  I can't see the TextView content. I've tried ii with a real device and several emulators. I am totally lost with Constraint Layout :(

Comment: I ditch constraintlayout on most of my projects - why dont you use something more familiar